# Visual Studio Build Notification

Tags: visual-studio-2017

In Visual Studio 2015, the build notification program used to pop up a Window. Since I've upgraded to VS 2017, it now produces a toast notification, which is easy to miss, and once it has faded (about 5 seconds), there is no way to get it back. The notification seems to be the only place where the build reconciliation option is available.

Is there either a way to reconcile other than from the notification, or is there a way to configure the notification to be a window rather than toast?